# How to convert `json` object to string concatenation

Tags: javascript, json

how to convert json object

```js
dic = {
        a:"1",
        b:"2,3",
        c:"abc"
    }
```

spliced into

```
a=1&b=2,3&c=abc
```

Comment: Note that JSON is way to encode data as text. Objects are not JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Dictionary can be converted like this:

```
new URLSearchParams(json).toString()
```

Arrays can be converted like this:

```
new URLSearchParams(json).toString()
```